# Knowing focused element id before form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, focus, form-submit

I want to return focus to the html element (that fires submit of my form) after ajax checkings. because always my form is submitted the last focused element is always the submit button.

How can i know the previous elemnt that had the focus (in pure JS please)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return focus to the HTML element that fires submit of your form after AJAX checkings, you can use the `focus()` method in JavaScript. You can store the previous element that had the focus in a variable before the AJAX call and then use it to set the focus back to that element after the AJAX call.

Example:

```js
// Store the previously focused element
let previousElement = document.activeElement;

// Perform AJAX call
$.ajax({
  url: "your-url",
  success: function() {
    // Set focus back to the previously focused element
    previousElement.focus();
  }
});
```

To get the previously focused element in pure JavaScript, you can use the `document.activeElement` property. This property returns the currently focused element in the document. You can store this value in a variable before the AJAX call and then use it to set the focus back to that element after the AJAX call.

```js
// Store the previously focused element
let previousElement = document.activeElement;

// Perform AJAX call
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    // Set focus back to the previously focused element
    previousElement.focus();
  }
};
xhr.open("GET", "your-url", true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: ok thank you... i will try it asap

Comment: document.activeElement works fine when i submit the form with enter key, but the problem is when i do clic with the mouse on submit button ,  document.activeElement returns id of this button.  Any idea?